# code igniter extend show_error

Tags: codeigniter

I implemented a rollback mechanism for my php execution so if an error occurs it will pop a stack and undo actions. How can I add this hook so my function is called anytime show_error is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is no such hook available.You need to hack it.
Modify the function "show_error()" in CI_Exceptions class *(File: system/libraries/Exceptions.php)* as per your Requirement.

[This](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/188261/) should be a reference to start with.

**Update**:
You should extent CI_Exceptions rather then modifying in-place.

Comment: You should be able to just extend `CI_Exceptions`, instead of modifying the system folder.

Comment: Actually I just realized, I also want this to happen when an exception happens not just when I manually use show_error function. Any way to do this for any exceptions and show_error alike?

Comment: @Rocket, True. 
@user391986, you should extent `CI_Exceptions` rather then modifying in-place. AFAIK, same `show_error()` should work in both the case.

Comment: I think so, so basically I extended to MY_Exceptions and put it in the core folder. So do I have to recopy the entire show_error function into my extended file or is there a way to just add on to it?

Comment: @user391986, You need to copy it and modify as required.

Comment: Got it, one more question, my entire rollback functionality is done within a library I created. So I wanted to add the function call within show_error which does the rollback. However if show_error is used from a different context the library might not have been loaded. Is it good enough design if I just put the function call of my custom library rollback inside of a try catch within the show_error function?

Comment: actually I tried the try catch technique but if the library is not loaded I get Fatal error: Call to a member function rollBackNow() on a non-object

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. As you are doing rollback, nothing functional is started unless the controller is loaded. And at this moment the library will also be available. Just make sure that you add the library to _autoload_.

Comment: Ah ah ! The link points to... a show_error() generated page !