# Hook in codeIgniter for display_error, How to implement?

Tags: codeigniter

How am I able to alter display_error (DB_driver.php) by hook?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125551/code-igniter-extend-show-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008767/how-to-get-show-error-in-codeigniter-to-load-a-view

Please refer these url that may give a good idea?

Comment: as per the codeIgnitor - The Database classes can not be extended or replaced with your own classes. All other classes are able to be replaced/extended. so it means we are not able to extend display_errror, so this is not possible am I correct, or any one give me good idea?

Comment: $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; set to FLASE in case of RESTful Services because you need to require json response but you cannot alter by hook.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks must be enabled, in ./application/config/config.php (about line 94)

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

Must be set to true.